# Using SharePoint as a shift/schedule management tool?

Tags: information-management, schedule, time

Is there an intuitive or functional way to use SharePoint (office 365 version) to manage employee weekly shifts?

Instead of just spreadsheets, SharePoint can allow our dispatchers can find an available tech by searching all of the metadata such as regions or cities.

I have already built a list to do this, grouped by region and subgrouped by week, and our dispatchers are loving it because it allows them search the name of the city they need service in and find a list of available techs (from over 100 techs)

[image]

However, it's currently very frustrating to manage by our managers because each tech's shift changes every week. That is currently the biggest challange because it consumes a lot of time of our managers to add each tech for each week, months worth of shifts for a 100 techs.

I tried looking into workflows that can duplicate weeks worth for each submission, but that's work in progress.

I was hoping there is a better way, such as the SharePoint Calendar app or InfoPath+Workflows that can add multiple weeks ahead. I've also tried Microsoft StaffHub, but it has no search function.

Thank you.

Comment: How are the shifts decided? As in does one tech tend to have the same schedule every week, or do they change at regular/predictable intervals outside of emergency issues/sick days? Is this something that the technicians could do themselves, and have manager approval?

Comment: hi @KGlasier The schedules are already decided by management outside of sharepoint (to secure techs availability), and any changes (such as emergencies, sick days or vacations) are modified by the manager/editor.

Answer (score 2):

Check **Shifts** functionality on Teams to have a whole tool for this stuff. This is the Microsoft bet inside the Office 365 suite for first line workers shift management.

Comment: This would have been wonderful but for our purpose it does not have search functionality nor metadata for assigned cities. Thanks though!